# Visual Studio Crashing on Solution Load

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, crash

Visual Studio crashes every time I open up a solution that I've been working on. It started happening seemingly out of nowhere, i.e. no significant changes to the solution were made.

It seems to be fine when no solution is loaded - it sits idle and doesn't crash. However, when I open my solution, it crashes within 15 seconds. Sometimes it crashes immediately, sometimes just a little after it loads the projects within the solution. I've tried loading other solutions and it seems to work fine.

It would seem that the problem is the solution, so I've tried deleting the `.suo` file and the other related solution fixing methods that I've found on SO but nothing has worked so far. I've tried running in safemode as well. And yes, I've tried restarting the computer already.

The Visual Studio logs don't seem to have any useful error messages, but event viewer comes up with the same error on every crash, making it a good lead but I have no idea what it means. And my searches about this error have come up dry.

Edit: Just tried running a repair on Visual Studio - no luck.

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Here's the error message from event viewer:

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The application requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast(string message).
Message: System.BadImageFormatException: Invalid public key token.
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReaderExtensions.CreateAssemblyIdentityOrThrow(MetadataReader reader, Version version, AssemblyFlags flags, BlobHandle publicKey, StringHandle name, StringHandle culture, Boolean isReference)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReaderExtensions.GetReferencedAssembliesOrThrow(MetadataReader reader)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.PEModule.get_ReferencedAssemblies()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.PEAssembly..ctor(AssemblyMetadata owner, ImmutableArray`1 modules)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.AssemblyMetadata.GetOrCreateData()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.AssemblyMetadata.GetModules()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FindSymbols.SymbolTreeInfo.GetModuleMetadata(Metadata metadata)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FindSymbols.SymbolTreeInfo.CreateMetadataSymbolTreeInfo(Solution solution, VersionStamp version, PortableExecutableReference reference, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FindSymbols.SymbolTreeInfo.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<LoadOrCreateMetadataSymbolTreeInfoAsync>b__0(VersionStamp version)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FindSymbols.SymbolTreeInfo.<LoadOrCreateAsync>d__54`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FindSymbols.SymbolTreeInfo.<GetInfoForMetadataReferenceAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.IncrementalCaches.SymbolTreeInfoIncrementalAnalyzerProvider.IncrementalAnalyzer.<UpdateReferenceAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.IncrementalCaches.SymbolTreeInfoIncrementalAnalyzerProvider.IncrementalAnalyzer.<UpdateSymbolTreeInfoAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.SolutionCrawlerRegistrationService.WorkCoordinator.IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor.<>c__DisplayClass33_1`1.<<RunAnalyzersAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.SolutionCrawlerRegistrationService.WorkCoordinator.IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor.<GetOrDefaultAsync>d__35`2.MoveNext()
Stack:
   at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String, System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FailFast.OnFatalException(System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ErrorReporting.FatalError.Report(System.Exception, System.Action`1<System.Exception>)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.SolutionCrawlerRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<GetOrDefaultAsync>d__35`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.SolutionCrawlerRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<GetOrDefaultAsync>d__35`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.SolutionCrawlerRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<GetOrDefaultAsync>d__35`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<GetOrDefaultAsync>d__35`2<System.__Canon,System.__Canon> ByRef)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.SolutionCrawlerRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor.GetOrDefaultAsync[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.__Canon, System.Func`3<System.__Canon,System.Threading.CancellationToken,System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.__Canon>>, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.SolutionCrawlerRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<RunAnalyzersAsync>d__33`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.__Canon)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.SolutionCrawlerRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<GetOrDefaultAsync>d__35`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.__Canon)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.SolutionCrawlerRegistrationService+WorkCoordinator+IncrementalAnalyzerProcessor+<>c__DisplayClass33_1`1+<<RunAnalyzersAsync>b__0>d[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionCrawler.AggregateIncrementalAnalyzer+<AnalyzeDocumentAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.SetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.DesignerAttribute.AbstractDesignerAttributeIncrementalAnalyzer+<AnalyzeDocumentAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VersionStamp, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]].TrySetResult(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VersionStamp)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VersionStamp, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]].SetResult(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VersionStamp)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker+<GetDependentVersionAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VersionStamp, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]].TrySetResult(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VersionStamp)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VersionStamp, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]].SetResult(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VersionStamp)
   at Roslyn.Utilities.AsyncLazy`1+Request[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VersionStamp, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]].CompleteFromTaskSynchronously(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VersionStamp>)
   at Roslyn.Utilities.AsyncLazy`1+Request[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VersionStamp, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]].CompleteFromTaskSynchronouslyStub(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Comment: You need to get your machine fixed, one of the DLLs that is used by VS got corrupted.  Repair won't fix that.  Disk corruption is not a good kind of problem to have, best to replace it asap.

Comment: I had this problem one day and resolved it by replacing all the business DLLs referenced in the projects. I guess one of them were corrupted but Idon't think it had to do with .NET errors